# Permuting outcome variable to estimate null likelihood ratio distribution for Poisson GLM

Tags: generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, likelihood-ratio, permutation-test, type-i-and-ii-errors

I fit a Poisson GLM using a set of candidate explanatory variables ($\lambda = e^{\beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{1}+\beta_{2}x_{2}+...}$), tested against the global null hypothesis ($\lambda = e^{\beta_{0}}$) using the likelihood ratio test, and obtained $p < 0.05$.

To confirm my control of type 1 error, I want to use randomization to eliminate the relationship between explanatory variables $X$ and count outcomes $y$, repeat the likelihood ratio test against the global null hypothesis, and confirm that I obtain p < 0.05 only 5% of the time.

I randomly shuffle $y$ relative to $X$, re-fit the GLM, perform the likelihood ratio test against the global null hypothesis, and record a p-value. I do this 1000 times.

Shuffling should remove any relationship between $y$ and $X$, so I expect a 5% hit rate at $\alpha = 0.05$. To my surprise, $p$ is less than $0.05$ more than 12% of the time.

Python code for a reproducible example is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import stats
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.tools.tools import add_constant

def lr_test(full_model_log_likelihood, full_model_df, null_model_log_likelihood, null_model_df):
    lr_stat = -2 * (null_model_log_likelihood - full_model_log_likelihood)
    difference_in_df = full_model_df - null_model_df
    return stats.chi2.sf(lr_stat, df=difference_in_df)
   
# Generate a design matrix of size n x k
X = np.random.random((10000,10))
# y only depends on the first column of X and a constant; the other features are noise
y = np.random.poisson(lam=np.exp(X[:,0]+0.5))

model = sm.GLM(endog=y, exog=add_constant(X), family=sm.families.Poisson()).fit()
null = sm.GLM(endog=y, exog=np.full(X.shape[0],1), family=sm.families.Poisson()).fit()

print('LR Test: p = {}'.format(lr_test(model.llf, model.df_model, null.llf, null.df_model)))

p = np.empty(1000)
for i in range(1000):
    np.random.shuffle(y)
    permuted_model = sm.GLM(endog=y, exog=add_constant(X), family=sm.families.Poisson()).fit()
    p[i] = lr_test(permuted_model.llf, permuted_model.df_model, null.llf, null.df_model)
    
print('Fraction of randomized models where p<0.05: {}'.format(np.sum(p<0.05)/1000))
```

returns

```
LR Test: p = 0.0
Fraction of randomized models where p<0.05: 0.145
```

To summarize, **when I generate a distribution of likelihood ratios under a null hypothesis of no relationship between y and X achieved by randomly permuting y relative to X, why is my apparent type 1 error so high?**

I believe my error might lie in a misuse of permutation testing in the case of Poisson noise, because when I run a similar simulation using a Gaussian-distributed variable $y$ and fit OLS models, the procedure above does successfully result in the expected type 1 error rate.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: "Eliminating the relationship" among the $X$'s is inconsistent with this model, which concerns *conditional* distributions of $y,$ not the full multivariate distribution.

Comment: @whuber, thanks for the reply. To clarify, I do not shuffle columns of $X$ - only $y$ relative to the rows of $X$. Under null hypothesis, I thought the distribution of $y$ should be independent of the rows of design matrix $X$. Not sure I understand why permuting is invalid because the "model concerns conditional distributions of $y$". Can you elaborate?